# Android Airplane Mode Detection for Honeycomb

Tags: android, mode, connectivity, airplane-mode

I am having trouble detecting airplane mode enabled/disabled on honeycomb, the following broadcast receiver works fine on all versions/sets other than android 3.0/ honeycomb/tablets..

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".ConnectivityReceiver">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE"/>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could directly poll if you are having problems

```
  private static boolean isAirplaneModeOn(Context context) {

        return Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;

    }
```

Or use [ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED)